# rails association belongs_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, belongs-to

I know sty must be wrong in the way I build my db but please take a minute answering this : I am building a supermarket model, where 1 user has a shopping list, each list has many products.
So what I do is :

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :lists
end

class List < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :products
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  ????
end
```

A list has several products but products don't belong to lists. What should I do to have Users having many lists, and lists having many products ?
regards,

Answer (score 0):

Have a class that links them via has_many through.

```
class ListItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :list
  belongs_to :product
end

class List < ActiveRecord::Base 
  belongs_to :user 
  has_many :list_items
  has_many :products, through: :list_items
end
```

Comment: I can't believe i need an extra Class to do this. This ind of association is useful and happens all the time I guess. Would you have to manage a list of users having shopping lists with items, is it the way you would proceed ?

Comment: You can use has_and_belongs_to_many instead, which you have the db table but no model.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need an additional class. Rails can manage this for you with the [has_and_belongs_to_many_association](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association)

In your case, it would be:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :lists
end

class List < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_and_belongs_to_many :products
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :lists
end
```

Of course, you need to add the join table in the migration:

```
create_table :lists_products, id: false do |t|
  t.belongs_to :list
  t.belongs_to :product
end
```